# How to run django-admin.py, when django is in an egg?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, buildout

I have inherited a project, which was deployed with buildout and is running fine. I've made  some changes in the translation .po file, but to compile to .mo file I need to run

```
django-admin.py compilemessages
```

How can I do this, when the only place I find django-admin.py is in an egg? The project is not using virtualenv.

Comment: Did you try using manage.py?

Comment: manage.py is also only in eggs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there was a django file, which set all of the eggs to be in sys.path, and then passed commands to django. I don't know if that is standard in buildout, though.

Comment: Ah, you mean there was a `bin/django`? That one is not standard in buildout, but your project apparently used the "djangorecipe" buildout recipe. That gives you a `bin/django`, which is effectively the same as the `django-admin.py`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using `virtualenv` then everything should be on your `PYTHONPATH`. With that in mind look at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/bin/django-admin.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from django.core import management

if __name__ == "__main__":
    management.execute_from_command_line()
```

Not the big deal to make your own `django-admin.py`, isn't it? And that should do the trick. But don't forget to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env variable.

Comment: If only it was that simple. There is a wsgi file, which sets the path to all the eggs included in the project.

Comment: @Euphorbium well, to me it's definitly separate problem. Just set the same paths in this `django-admin.py`.